# AKKA receive reference to message

Tags: scala, akka

In Java the declaration of onReceive includes a reference to the message as an object.

```
public void onReceive( Object message )
{
    if( message instanceof MyClass )
    {
```

In Scala however no such reference is included and cases are specific

```
def receive {
  case "test" => println("ttt")
 }
```

Is there a way to access the received message in Scala? I would like, for example, to manually forward any unknown messages to a specific actor. Something like

```
def receive {
  case "test" => println("ttt")
  case _ => AnotherActor ! TheMessage
 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is amazingly simple:

```
def receive {
  case "test" => println("ttt")
  case theMessage => AnotherActor ! theMessage
}
```

Comment: But in this case theMessage would have to be a declared case class. What if I want a catch all case where I can forward unknown cases to a remote actor, in the hope that they have knowledge of it?

Comment: nope, here it is just an alias that will catch all unknown cases, not class

Comment: You are right, tested and it works. As soon as I can I mark as answered.

Comment: You need to use "forward" or AnotherActor.tell(theMessage, sender) to forward the message in the right sense (i.e. by retaining the original sender)

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if the Scala API had a `currentMessage` similar to `sender`.   Of course the same caveats would apply to not [closing over the actor's state/methods](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.5/general/jmm.html#jmm-shared-state).

For example, if your actor response to a dozen messages, the method suggested by om-nom-nom may not be practical.

Here is one way to solve the problem:

```
var currentMessage: Any = _

object saveMessage extends Receive {
  def isDefinedAt(x: Any) = { currentMessage = x; false }
  def apply(x: Any) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("saveMessage apply") }
}

def receive = saveMessage orElse {
  case Foo(x) => // do something special for Foo
  case Bar(y) => // something different for Bar
  case Baz(z) => // something else
  case Bip(a) => // etc
  case Bop(b, c) => .......
}
```

Assuming that all of the above end up calling a common method at some point that needs access to the current message, this could come in handy.

But again - never close over `currentMessage` (I'm guess that danger is why it's not in the current API).

Answer (score 0):

I use this helper method (based on sourcedelica)

```
  def extractMessage(msgToReceive: Any => Receive): Receive = {
    var msg: Any = null
    new Receive {
      def isDefinedAt(x: Any) = {
        msg = x
        false
      }

      def apply(x: Any) {
        ???
      }
    } orElse msgToReceive(msg)
  }
```

Usage:

```
override def receive = extractMessage( msg => {
  //your normal receive cases here:
  case "one thing" => 
  case "another" =>
})
```